# Can I use Azure DevOps CI/CD to deploy a site within a virtual machine's IIS website (and not others hosted alongside)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I plan to have several CI/CD pipelines publish to a single IIS server that is hosted in Azure, but ideally could be deployed to locally (pull).

Is there any way to configure a yaml or other pipeline action to allow for

1. more than one project or pipeline to use the same target host
2. (if you know) if that project or pipeline on the host is scoped to "Subscription" or something else

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, If the answer resolved your question, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you should be able to configure the service connection and re-use it among multiple pipelines without an issue.

You'll create the AzureRM service connection within the project and apply that connection to both pipelines within the task settings (assuming you're using an Azure deployment task).

An alternative would be to remote into the IIS server and register it as a deployment group (or agent if you're using YAML) and set it as your pool when configuring your pipelines.

Here's more information on how to set up an agent if you take that route:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install